# update_or_create Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, updates

Hi I have live data coming in from an API,  Since we have the same SKU, in multiple markets, I need a composite PK, (SKU, Country),
I know Django  does not support this, so I am using the update_or_create function.

My issue is that the data keeps duplicating as the quantity values change

```
country merch quantity sku
USA CC  2807    1005    B00VQVPRH8  
USA CC  2806    1004    B00VQVPRH8
```

Here is the call to save the data:

```
obj, created = FBAInventory.objects.update_or_create(
    Account=merchant["company"],
    ASIN=ASIN, 
    TotalSupplyQuantity=TotalSupplyQuantity,
    InStockSupplyQuantity=InStockSupplyQuantity,
    FNSKU=FNSKU,
    EarliestAvailability=EarliestAvailability,
    defaults={'SellerSKU': SellerSKU, 'Country': merchant["country"]},
)
```

Am I using the function incorrectly, I want to update the SKU/Country row, I do not want a duplicate with different quantity values. I know I can use get, but I want to take advantage of this function so I don't have to write a conditional statement. Should defaults hold the update values and the kwarg hold the values to match?

ANSWER:

```
        obj, created = FBAInventory.objects.update_or_create(
        Account=merchant["company"],
        ASIN=ASIN, 
        FNSKU=FNSKU,
        defaults={'SellerSKU': SellerSKU, 'Country': merchant["country"],
        'TotalSupplyQuantity':TotalSupplyQuantity,'InStockSupplyQuantity':InStockSupplyQuantity, 'EarliestAvailability':EarliestAvailability }
       )
```

per MrName suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that all provided keyword arguments will create the matching criteria. Since you are passing quantity as the keyword arguments, the method is looking for an existing record with that quantity, and not finding it, hence creating a duplicate.

If the move the quantity arguments into `defaults`, your code should successfully locate the existing record based on the desired search criteria (like account for example), and then update the quantity.